How can I change the css with js while fetching data?
I want to fetch data but I want it to show less data each time the screen gets smaller. How can I do that?
I tried this, but I have no idea whether it's correct or not:
const category = async() => {
  try {
    let movie = document.querySelector(".category");
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 992px)')
    var picture = document.getElementsByClassName('.movies');

    function media(mediaQuery) {
      if (mediaQuery.matches) {
        movie.classList.add("movie:nth-child(odd) ")
      }
    }
    movie.classList.add("movie");
    let data = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/movies");
    let res = await data.json();
    let movies = res.map((elem) => {
      return `
        <div class="picture">
          <div class="overlay"></div>
          <img src=${elem.image} alt=${elem.alt}>
        </div>
      `;
    });
    document
      .querySelector(".movies")
      .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", movies.join(""));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};


This type of thing is usually better done with media queries in the CSS, rather than JavaScript.

Also: what do you mean by "show less data"? Are you showing fewer rows? Hiding parts of the UI? etc...

Try this code, for controling of your screens use css, it is better (@media).
CSS:


/* Define the basic styles for the movies container */
.movies {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Default to showing 2 items per row */
.picture {
  width: 50%;
}

/* For larger screens, show more items per row */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .picture {
    width: 33.33%; /* Show 3 items per row */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .picture {
    width: 25%; /* Show 4 items per row */
  }
}



JS (AND HTML):


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Movie List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="movies"></div>
  <script>
    const fetchMovies = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/movies");
        const movies = await response.json();

        // Function to update the number of displayed movies
        const updateMoviesDisplay = () => {
          const container = document.querySelector(".movies");
          container.innerHTML = ""; // Clear existing content

          const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
          let itemsPerRow;
          if (windowWidth >= 992) {
            itemsPerRow = 4; // Large screens
          } else if (windowWidth >= 768) {
            itemsPerRow = 3; // Medium screens
          } else {
            itemsPerRow = 2; // Small screens
          }

          const visibleMovies = movies.slice(0, itemsPerRow * 2); // Show twice the number of items per row
          visibleMovies.forEach(movie => {
            const movieElement = `
              <div class="picture">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <img src="${movie.image}" alt="${movie.alt}">
              </div>
            `;
            container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", movieElement);
          });
        };

        // Initial display
        updateMoviesDisplay();

        // Update display on window resize
        window.addEventListener("resize", updateMoviesDisplay);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching movies:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchMovies();
  </script>
</body>
</html>



